# Как в nuxt.config.js получить текущую локаль и довавить её в headers axios

Tags: javascript, axios, nuxt.js, i18n

Использую NuxtJS, как вывести выбранную пользователем локаль в заголовки axios? Что бы при запросе к бэкенду передавался заголовок 'Accept-Language' с выбранной локалью.

nuxt.config.js

```
...
  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/axios
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/pwa
    '@nuxtjs/pwa',
    '@nuxtjs/i18n',
  ],

  i18n: {
    nuxtI18nHead: true,
    strategy: 'prefix_except_default',
    defaultLocale: "en",    
    locales: [
      {
        code: 'de',
        ico: 'de-DE',
        file: 'de-DE.json'
      },
      {
        code: 'ru',
        ico: 'ru-RU',
        file: 'ru-RU.json'
      },
      {
        code: 'en',
        ico: 'en-US',
        file: 'en-US.json'
      },
    ],
    detectBrowserLanguage: {
      useCookie: true,
      cookieKey: "i18n_redirected",
      alwaysRedirect: false,
      fallbackLocale: "en",
      redirectOn: 'root',
    }
  },

  // Axios module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-axios
  axios: {
    baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
    headers: {
      common: {
        'Accept-Language': 'en' /// Получить тут выбранную локаль
      },      
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В конфиг не получится. Он работает только при компиляции.

Если в компоненте, то

```
this.$axios.setHeader('Accept-Language', this.$i18n.locale )
```

Если в плагинах, то можно попробовать:

```
export default function ({ app, $axios }) {
  $axios.setHeader('Accept-Language', app.i18n.locale )
  app.i18n.onLanguageSwitched = (oldLocale, newLocale) => {
    $axios.setHeader('Accept-Language', newLocale )
  }
}
```

https://axios.nuxtjs.org/helpers/

https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/callbacks